# Jquery DIV count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the number of  elements under a parent  but its giving me an incorrect count. The result should be 2, where as its returning me 4.

My HTML structure is:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;" id="parentDiv" class="scroll">

<div id="3">
  <table id="t3" class="Table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="b3" class="bY"><table id="inner1" width="100%" cellpadding="3">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="code" id="code3" width="172"></td>
                <td class="Num" id="Num3" width="50"></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="Name" id="Name"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="code" width="172"></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="serial" width="110"></td>
                <td class="serial" width="322"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

 <div id="4" >
  <table id="t4" class="Table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="b4" class="bY"><table id="inner1" width="100%" cellpadding="3">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="code" id="code4" width="172"></td>
                <td class="Num" id="Num4" width="50"></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="Name" id="Name"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="code" width="172">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="serial" width="110"></td>
                <td class="serial" width="322"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and the code I am using to count is:

```
var numofDivs = $("#parentDiv div").size();
alert(numofDivs);
```

and if I am using the following code, the result is coming 1 (which is incorrect too).

```
var numofDivs = $("#parentDiv > div").size();
alert(numofDivs);
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question - both of your solutions give the correct number of divs underneath parentDiv. Here is my example in jsFiddle - http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZNBXz/

Comment: Seems to work fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/F66xA/ Alert says 2

Comment: I find your code works fine too - perhaps you have another element with the id of parentDiv?

Comment: Folks, this is the HTML I am working on:

Comment: re: folks -- then your HTML isn't valid, your #parentDiv tag is never closed :P

Comment: Hi Jason, Actually that div didnt copy. In Actual code I do have that DIV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you should use the function children()

```
$("#parentDiv").children("div").length
```

the function gives you an array and ten you can get the length.

and in the children function you can specify what tags to filter, but you can also leave it blank and it will give you all the children

[check the API](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: More succinctly: $('#parentDiv > div').length

Comment: Statement _"you should use the function children"_ is incorrect, as current OP's solution provides same functionality and also simpler.

Answer (score 0):

With the give HTML code, your code to count the elements is correct, and both ways should return two.

So, the conclusion is that the HTML code doesn't actually look the way that you describe it. A structure that would give that result could for example look like this:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <div>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

If you want to count the first level of `div` elements that you encounter, you would have to do it recursively, i.e. for each child element check if it's a div element or count the number of first level div elements it contains:

```
function countDivs(element) {
  var cnt = 0;
  $(element).children().each(function(){
    cnt += this.tagName === 'DIV' ? 1 : countDivs(this);
  })
  return cnt;
}

$(function(){
  alert(countDivs($('#parentDiv').get(0)));
});
```